# Active Admin Name Error uninitializedconstant Resource::Users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, nameerror, uninitialized-constant

So I have a couple of models in my app and they are all registered with ActiveAdmin. They all work great except for one and I can't figure out why. I keep getting the same error:

> NameError at /admin/reports
>   uninitialized constant Report::Users

The model that it is happening on is called `Report`

```
    class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :users
      belongs_to :cars
      enum reason: [:accident,:totaled,:stolen]
      validates :reason, presence:true
    end
```

The controller looks like this:

```
Class ReportsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!


  def create
    @car=Car.find(params[:car_id])
    @report=@car.reports.build(report_params)
    @report.user_id=current_user.id
    @report.car_id=@car.id
    if @report.save
      redirect_to car_path(car)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @report=Report.find(params[:id])
    @report.destroy
  end

  private
  def report_params
    params.require(:report).permit(:reason)
  end
end
```

This is the migration used to create the model:

```
class CreateReports < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :reports do |t|
      t.references :user, index: true
      t.references :car, index: true
      t.integer :reason, default: 0

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_foreign_key :reports, :users
    add_foreign_key :reports, :cars
  end
end
```

Lastly here is the active_admin app/admin/report.rb:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Report do

# See permitted parameters documentation:
# https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/2-resource-customization.md#setting-up-strong-parameters
#
# permit_params :list, :of, :attributes, :on, :model
#
# or
#
# permit_params do
#   permitted = [:permitted, :attributes]
#   permitted << :other if resource.something?
#   permitted
# end


end
```

I have been trying to figure it out for a couple of hours. Solutions that I saw on SO that don't work. I ran `rails generate active_admin:resource Report` to create it so it is singular.  Why is it misbehaving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> NameError at /admin/reports uninitialized constant Report::Users

***Association name*** for a `belongs_to` should be ***singular*** as per naming conventions.

```
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user #here
belongs_to :car #and here too
enum reason: [:accident,:totaled,:stolen]
validates :reason, presence:true
end
```